# df.city.unique() returns different name order than groupby(['city'])

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to plot the total sales group by city and match the bars the corresponding city and I used the following code:

```
best_city = all_data.groupby(['city']).sum()
city = df.city.unique()
plt.bar(city, best_city['Total'])
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

The city returned 'Atlanta, Austin, Boston'
but the x label for the bars were 'Boston, Atlanta, Austin'

So I'm wondering how to match the bar with the correct name?

Comment: groupby be default sorts the order , try `all_data.groupby(['city'],sort=False).sum()`

Comment: I tried this and it worked out perfect, so thanks! But I'm just curious that the order of the results are the same for unique() and groupby, as long as I do not let groupby sort by passing False to it?

Comment: `"Uniques are returned in order of appearance. Hash table-based unique, therefore does NOT sort."`- this is from unique documentation, so unique does not sort the data but groupby by default does. so no the order of unique and groupby are not always same :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
best_city = all_data.groupby(['city']).sum()

best_city.plot.bar()
# or from your code:
# best_city['Total'].plot.bar()
```